# GIF ONLY visible in IE BUT not in Firefox, Photoshop or any other app

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, gif, invisible

Please visit the following page with Firefox or any other browser AND Internet Explorer:
http://uni-ka.the-jens.de/html/mathe4/mase2.htm

You'll see the pictures (formulas) are just visible in IE. How is this done?
Furthermore you'll see it has nothing to do with html source, only with the picture:

- Download any of these pictures and try to view them. Some apps show a white picture, some a black picture and others a transparency-patterned picture.
- Assuming you downloaded the first picture from the given page above (`ma63x.gif`) make a copy and open it with hex or text editor and add some of these signs `ÿþýû÷ïß¿` starting in line 8 col 374 or at position 1218 (decimal). After saving, some apps will tell you now that the gif file has no valid format.
- Let's say you stored the manipulated copy as `my.g` then save those to lines as a htm/html file and open it in Firefox and again in IE.

  > img src="ma63x.gif"
  >
  > img src="my.g"

Firefox will still not show the picture (I use version 3.6, maybe 4.0 is able to render the gif). IE will now show you the original and your copy. Compare both and play a little with adding and removing signs in your copy.

Now my questions:

- Is there any app that uses this "feature" because I could not even see something useful in Photoshop (just one black layer in index color mode)?
- Why can only IE show the picture correctly?
- Do you know how to manually manipulate the gif as mentioned above in a sense full way?

Comment: What program did you use to create this image with? I've seen this behavior with some programs before.

Comment: I didn't create these pictures. Google and pde solving brought me to that page but. I thought the author used this to protect his/her pictures or something like that.

Comment: Page is down, the question is worthless now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I examined the first image on the page, and found that my theories were correct. I found these settings:

```
Viewport width = 363
Viewport height = 28

Image position = 190, 448
Image width = 363
Image height = 28

Comment: Image generated by AFPL Ghostscript (device=pnmraw)
```

So, the image is placed outside the viewport.

Chrome expands the viewport to include the image, while IE and Opera ignores the viewport and only shows the image (or ignores the placement of the image). Firefox does what the format specifies, i.e. only shows the viewport and the parts of the image that is visible inside it.

According the comment the image was created using AFPL Ghostscript, which is a Postscript interpreter, so it was probably converted from Postscript to GIF.

I edited the file to change the Image position to 0,0, and then it works just fine:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks Guffa and Pekka for your fast and reliable answers. I thought it has something to do with IE and being a security "feature". How did you find out what was the creating app?

Comment: @DragJo: The file contains a comment section with the text that I showed above. I viewed the file as a binary file using Visual Studio, and examined it using a file format example on Wikipedia.

Comment: Well, you can't but +1 a person who goes and manually reads the *actual bytes* from the headers. :)

Comment: Absolutely cool...
To all those quarreling with themselves (like me) Windows stores in little endian so if you try to find 363dec=0x16B it'll say 6B01 in binary view. Thanks a lot Guffa & Pekka.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your GIFs.

This is what the image looks like in Chrome without the size constraint (the vast amounts of space are a part of the image)

[image]

so the image data is always there, but Chrome reads the image as large (with the size constraints in the tags forcing it to resize the whole thing), and IE reading it as small.

I think the application that generated the GIF files must be storing odd values in the header data.

What works for me to fix them is opening the images in [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de), and saving them again as GIF files.

Comment: Thanks for your hint with IrfanView.

Comment: The GIF format has separate sizes for its viewport and the images shown in the viewport. It's possible that the image is placed completely outside the viewport, and it seems that some browsers adjust the viewport to contain the image, while some other browsers ignore the viewport and only displays the image. In that case what Firefox does would actually be the most correct according to the file format specifications, i.e. display the viewport and only the parts of the image that falls inside the viewport.

Comment: @Guffa ah-ha, that makes a *lot* of sense! In that case, IE is indeed the one screwing it up. Chrome and FF are showing the entire viewport then, but the `width` and `height` constraints force it into so small a size that the content becomes invisible

Comment: @Pekka, when I downloaded the file manually its size was just 363*28 like the width and height tag in source tell me but your picture is 553*476 and thus makes it a completly different file. How did you manage to download it that way?

Comment: @DragJo it depends on which program you open it. IrfanView reads it as 363*28, others (like PhotoImpact) take the whole viewport

Comment: @Pekka, thanks for another app suggestion ;) I will try it later. Since I realized that I almost know nothing about the file spec... so in this context one last stupid question: What is the REAL size of the image?